# Expression Blend-Api (Blend 4) vs. Visual Studio 2012

Tags: expression-blend-4, blend-2012

I have a project that defines a Blend behavior. The Blend SDK used to create this behavior is Version 4. In Visual Studio 2010 I can work with this with no trouble at all. In VS 2012, the WPF Designer seems to have issues with the dll.

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:MyLib.Util.Behaviors;assembly=MyLib"
xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyLib;assembly=MyLib"
```

In the WPF designer's intellisense neither namespaces appear, so I have to blind-type them.

Despite the fact that the designer would not propose the namespaces of `MyLib` and `Interactivity`, I can instantiate a control defined in `MyLib` and have perfect intellisense for that:

```
<v:ViewPort></v:ViewPort>
```

Now I want to add a Behavior to the `ViewPort`, the one defined in `MyLib.Util.Behaviors`

```
<v:ViewPort>
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <b:ZoomAreaBehavior />
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</v:ViewPort>
```

But again, there's no intellisense for `b:ZoomAreaBehavior`. The error list says that ZoomAreaBehavior could not be found. The very same code works in 2010 and will compile and run as soon as I close the Visual Editor.

Does anyone have an idea what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Blend** *support* was added in Update 1, **Blend for Visual Studio 2012**, Update 2 has WPF support built in.